# What's the best way to update locale in Laravel when using Vue components and Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a Laravel project that starts the user off on a page comprised of Vue component files where I'm using the i18n.js library to translate the text in the components and is updated via a toggle on my header.vue file. I also need to carry this locale over when the user goes to register which is all in blade.php extensions and is using the `Auth::routes();` provided by Laravel.

I've previously tried to create cookies within JavaScript in the Vue components and I have it so it can recognise the update in my header.blade.php file however, this is purely cosmetic and doesn't actually apply the correct locale to the config and use the data stored in `resources/lang/xx`.

I've asked a previous question where I was able to update the session locale via a URL on clicking a the toggle that mimics the one in header.vue however, this failed to update the cookie but changed the locale so the text would change in blade.php files but would not translate over to the vue files.

Code References:

web.php - Sets the session locale, set cookie returns encrypted and is only available under the URL

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function($locale){
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    setcookie('locale', $locale, time()+(60*60*24*10));
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

Header.vue - vue component that is persistent through the standard app

```
import i18n from '../../../lang/i18n';
export default{
  data(){
    lang: this.getLanguage()
  },
  methods:{
    switchLangauge(locale) {
      document.cookie = 'locale='+ locale;
      this.lang = locale;
      i18n.locale = locale;
    },
    getLanguag(){
      var x = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        var key = x[i].split('=')[0].trim();
        if(key == "locale"){
          return x[i].split('=')[1].trim();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

header.blade.php - replaces vue component when user wants to register/login

```
<li>
  <div id="toggle">
    <div class="lang {{ $_COOKIE['locale'] == 'en' ? 'selected' : '' }}">
       <a class="{{ $_COOKIE['locale'] == 'en' ? 'selected' : '' }}" href="{{ url('locale/en') }}">EN</a>
    </div>
    <div class="lang {{ $_COOKIE['locale'] == 'cy' ? 'selected' : '' }}">
      <a class="{{ $_COOKIE['locale'] == 'cy' ? 'selected' : '' }}" href="{{ url('locale/cy') }}">CY</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have been able to find https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website which is a way to do what I want to achieve in blade.php but it doesn't seem like it'd be able to be used in vue files and I can't check the code because the repo provided is down.

My question is: Is there a correct way to allow a user to be able to toggle their language choice and have that be maintained, going from a vue component to a blade.php page and vice versa, having the text change to match the chosen language on both types of file?

-EDIT- 27-01

I managed to find an article on using translations in vue.js using a service provider (https://dev.to/4unkur/how-to-use-laravel-translations-in-js-vue-files-ia) Is this the only/most effective way to achieve what I want? If I implement this the only issue I can see is that I wouldn't be able to set the cookie. Any help would be appreciated.

-EDIT- 28-01

I've tried to create a service provider however, I'm getting the error: `ReflectionException Class encrypter does not exist`, found solutions that state I need to run `php artisan key:generate` but I've already ran that to get the project up and running, does it need to be regenerated or should is there a way around it?